# Ag-Grid : Copy and paste from Excel (windows OS)

Tags: ag-grid, paste, cut

In Windows Operating system while copying Excel or LibreOffice cells of a single row  into ag-agrid cells,  causes the first ag-grid cell below  current row to be overwritten.
It works fine in Mac and Linux boxes.
I did test it in my application and in Ag-grid Demo as well. Both face the same bug.
In order to reproduce it, we select just one cell in ag-grid.
If I select 10 cells from excel and 10 cells into ag-agrid then it works fine.
In third image you can see that value of 100 has been lost.

BEFORE PASTE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2xQY.png)

DATA COPIED FROM EXCEL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xms0D.png)

AG-GRID AFTER PASTE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN7xa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid property **suppressLastEmptyLineOnPaste**, as described in the documentation

> Set to true to work around a bug with Excel (Windows) that adds an
> extra empty line at the end of ranges copied to the clipboard.
> Default: false

Link to the documenattion:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-properties/#reference-clipboard